# .htaccess rewrite redirected url

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

I have redirected my all .html pages to process.php with get parameter, now i want to clean the query url.

I have redirected like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /Site/process.php?dir=$1&page=$2 [R=301,L]
```

This gives url like this.

```
http://localhost/Site/process.php?dir=Directory&page=page.html
```

I want to clean this url back to original url like this and still be able to post get parameter.

```
http://localhost/Site/Directory/page.html
```

I have tried like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /Site/process.php?dir=$1&page=$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Site/$1/$2([^/.]+)/?$ [L]
```

But it does nothing.

Please see and suggest any possible way to this.

Thanks.

**Edit**

These html pages actually don't exist, just the link in pages, i want to process these link to make page from database using php and htaccess keeping url intact, can this be done.

Comment: Which directory is the docroot? Site? or above site?

Comment: If you keep the original URL and map silently the resource to the php file you are doing the same. At this moment you are redirecting the "pretty" URL to the "ugly" resource address but now you want to keep this resource address but show again the 'pretty' URL, which is going back to the starting point..

Comment: @ Felipe Alameda A- These html pages actually don't exist, just the link in pages, i want to process these link to make page from database using php and htaccess keeping url intact, can this be done.

Comment: You left a space between `@` and my user name so I didn't get your comment. I am kind of lost here, but in general terms the resource (The script) can be mapped to one address while the browser shows a "pretty" URL, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just wanting to leave the "html" part in the address bar to make "pretty URLs", just leave off the `[R]` flag, and drop the 2nd rule. The redirect will happen on the server, but the browser will still have the `.html` URL.

Comment: Its working. `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*\.html) /Site/process.php?dir=$1&page=$2 [L]` Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to `and still be able to post get parameter` part (pass full original query string to script):

`RewriteRule some.html some-other.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

May be helpful.